# Reverse string function in C?

Tags: c, string, reverse

Here's a C source I tried to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
    char c[81];

    gets(c);

    str_inv(c);

    puts(c);

}

void str_inv(char *s[])
{
    int i, j;
    char *temp;

    temp=calloc(1 ,strlen(s)*sizeof(char));

    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory not allocated.");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(i=0, j=strlen(s)-1; i<strlen(s); i++, j--)
    {
        temp[i]=s[j];
    }

    for(i=0; i<strlen(s); i++)
    {
        s[i]=temp[i];
    }

    free(temp);
}
```

An output of the program looks like this:

```
**abc**


**Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.262 s**
**Press any key to continue.**
```

The code in function `str_inv` works fine while in `main()` function, but not in separate function.

What is the problem with function?

Comment: 1) allocate space for null terminator 2) add print statement 3) traverse half of the string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char *s[]` is an array of pointer to `char`

`char s[]` is an array of `char`

Change the function to

```
void str_inv(char s[])
```

---

As a side note. `gets()` is deprecated, please do not use it. Use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) instead.